# Bootstrap table table-condensed table-hover, Top Border not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using custom css with bootstrap for outer border. but the top border isnt visible unless i make its size to 2 px.

how can i solve this?

HTML

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover border"> 
<tr><td>#</td><td><strong>name</strong></td></tr>
<tr><td>1.</td><td>one</td></tr>
<tr><td>2.</td><td>two</td></tr>
<tr><td>3.</td><td>three</td></tr>
<tr><td>4.</td><td>four</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.0.3/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css");

.border{
background-color:#fff;
color:#000;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #4C7ED1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xy6a6/

I would like a Outer Table Border of 1px #4C7ED1
Its visible on all sides except top , how can i fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border:1px double #4C7ED1;` instead of `border:1px solid #4C7ED1;`

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xy6a6/4/)**

Answer (score 6):

In bootstrap 4, the class `table-condensed` is renamed to `table-sm` for consistency.

- Reference: [Click here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#tables)

Answer (score 2):

[A JSFiddle with the fix](http://jsfiddle.net/Xy6a6/2/).

Delving into the DOM, you'll notice that it's the `<td>` that have a border-top property of `1px solid #ddd`. All you needed to do was select the `<td>`s within the first `<tr>` and then apply the border you wanted.

Ultimately, it meant adding this to your CSS:

```
.border tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 1px solid #4C7ED1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should change your first table inside tags to `thead` like this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover border"> 
<thead><td>#</td><td><strong>name</strong></td></thead>
<tr><td>1.</td><td>one</td></tr>
<tr><td>2.</td><td>two</td></tr>
<tr><td>3.</td><td>three</td></tr>
<tr><td>4.</td><td>four</td></tr>
</table>
```

then you'll have top border of table and you now you can modify css rule for this element

http://jsfiddle.net/Xy6a6/3/